# How do I refactor this Cypress fixtures code?

Tags: javascript, cypress, fixtures

I need help refactoring this Cypress code

```
let stripe;
  let bookService;
  let images;
  let moreDetails;
  let checkoutDetails;
  let wait;
  before(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.fixture('stripe').then((data) => {
      stripe = data;
    });
    cy.fixture('bookService').then((data) => {
      bookService = data;
    });
    cy.fixture('images').then((data) => {
      images = data;
    });
    cy.fixture('moreDetails').then((data) => {
      moreDetails = data;
    });
    cy.fixture('wait').then((data) => {
      wait = data;
    });
  });
```

I have tried

```
stripe = cy.fixture('stripe')
```

but it's returning an object { specWindow: ..., chainerId: ...}

Comment: Don't modify external variables from within a then. You'll run into issues

Comment: I am using fixture to get data before test like this 
```
let stripe;
  let bookService;
  let images;
  let moreDetails;
  let checkoutDetails;
  let wait;
  before(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.fixture('stripe').then((data) => {
      stripe = data;
    });
    cy.fixture('bookService').then((data) => {
      bookService = data;
    });
    cy.fixture('images').then((data) => {
      images = data;
    });
    cy.fixture('moreDetails').then((data) => {
      moreDetails = data;
    });
``` 
I hate repeating this in every test file

Comment: Please may you remove the comment and update the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ok to import fixtures at the to of the spec. You can use `require()` to refactor the fixtures in the way you suggest,

```js
let stripe = require('./cypress/fixtures/stripe.json')
let bookService = require('./cypress/fixtures/bookService.json')
let images = require('./cypress/fixtures/images.json')
let moreDetails = require('./cypress/fixtures/moreDetails.json')
let wait = require('./cypress/fixtures/wait.json')

before(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
});
```